# change in Android API level from 18 to 17, but android never "Boots Up"

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Have OpenGL ES 2.0 App, when I run it on emulator with `API level 18`, it runs smoothly, takes around 2 minutes(2k log messages).

Because my S4 has 4.2.2(`API level 17`), so I downloaded it and started testing on AVD with API level 17, but it never "boots up". I waited for 15 mins..

Also on my device App was not working, so I thought this version is the issue, but even when I have generated `.apk` using 4.2.2, it still does not work on device("Horrible Black Window... oh my OGL!")

Testing Env: Win7. (if it makes any difference)

=================================================================================
Edit: Seem to have found the pattern:

it starts failing with:

```
11-30 23:51:31.772: E/BatteryService(1436): usbOnlinePath not found
11-30 23:51:31.772: E/BatteryService(1436): wirelessOnlinePath not found
11-30 23:51:31.779: E/BatteryService(1436): batteryVoltagePath not found
11-30 23:51:31.779: E/BatteryService(1436): batteryTemperaturePath not found
...
11-30 23:51:32.129: E/PowerManagerService-JNI(1436): Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
...
```

then says it has failed to start core service:

```
11-30 23:51:41.809: E/System(1436): ******************************************
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436): ************ Failure starting core service
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 97 to 95
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4822)
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4432)
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installSystemProviders(ActivityThread.java:4970)
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.installSystemProviders(ActivityManagerService.java:6909)
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:282)  
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 97 to 95
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:361)
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:255)
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436):     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.establishDbTracking(SettingsProvider.java:386)
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436):     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.onCreate(SettingsProvider.java:326)
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436):     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4819)
11-30 23:51:41.829: E/System(1436):     ... 4 more
```

and finally says boot up has failed, many services die, and then again it tries to load all the libraries and tries to start the services, and again these very messages repeat.

```
11-30 23:51:41.829: I/SystemServer(1436): Input Method Service
11-30 23:51:41.892: W/InputMethodManagerService(1436): Couldn't create dir.: /data/system/inputmethod
11-30 23:51:41.959: D/ActivityThread(1436): Loading provider settings: com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider
11-30 23:51:42.119: W/SystemServer(1436): ***********************************************
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436): BOOT FAILURE starting Input Manager Service
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 97 to 95
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4822)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4473)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContextImpl.java:1987)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:1085)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.lazyGetProvider(Settings.java:764)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.getStringForUser(Settings.java:811)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at android.provider.Settings$Secure.getStringForUser(Settings.java:2772)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService$InputMethodSettings.getSelectedInputMethod(InputMethodManagerService.java:3850)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.<init>(InputMethodManagerService.java:672)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:361)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 97 to 95
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:361)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:255)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.establishDbTracking(SettingsProvider.java:386)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.onCreate(SettingsProvider.java:326)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4819)
11-30 23:51:42.139: A/SystemServer(1436):   ... 9 more
11-30 23:51:42.169: I/SystemServer(1436): Accessibility Manager
11-30 23:51:42.219: W/SystemServer(1436): ***********************************************
11-30 23:51:42.219: A/SystemServer(1436): BOOT FAILURE making display ready
11-30 23:51:42.219: A/SystemServer(1436): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 23:51:42.219: A/SystemServer(1436):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:377)
11-30 23:51:42.239: W/dalvikvm(1436): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
11-30 23:51:42.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1436): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: android.server.ServerThread
11-30 23:51:42.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1436): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 23:51:42.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.showBootMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:4352)
11-30 23:51:42.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:389)
11-30 23:51:42.259: I/Process(1436): Sending signal. PID: 1436 SIG: 9
11-30 23:51:42.309: I/Zygote(1233): Exit zygote because system server (1436) has terminated
11-30 23:51:42.339: E/installd(40): eof
11-30 23:51:42.339: E/installd(40): failed to read size
11-30 23:51:42.339: I/installd(40): closing connection
11-30 23:51:42.349: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'permission' died
11-30 23:51:42.349: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'scheduling_policy' died
11-30 23:51:42.349: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'telephony.registry' died
11-30 23:51:42.349: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'cpuinfo' died
11-30 23:51:42.349: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'accessibility' died
11-30 23:51:42.349: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'account' died
11-30 23:51:42.349: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'gfxinfo' died
11-30 23:51:42.349: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'package' died
11-30 23:51:42.349: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'activity' died
11-30 23:51:42.349: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'meminfo' died
11-30 23:51:42.349: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'dbinfo' died
11-30 23:51:42.349: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'entropy' died
11-30 23:51:42.349: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'power' died
11-30 23:51:42.349: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'usagestats' died
11-30 23:51:42.369: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'content' died
11-30 23:51:42.369: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'user' died
11-30 23:51:42.369: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'display' died
11-30 23:51:42.369: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'batteryinfo' died
11-30 23:51:42.369: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'sensorservice' died
11-30 23:51:42.479: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'media.audio_policy' died
11-30 23:51:42.479: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
11-30 23:51:42.479: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'media.player' died
11-30 23:51:42.479: I/ServiceManager(30): service 'media.camera' died
```

Before this edit, you did not have any clue what the heck is happening, now there is a log. I myself is pretty helpless, don't know what to try, so really hopeful about your help now.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to testing OpenGL, i would not advice you use emulator i.e AVD. Use devices as much as possible.